# How to monitor file changes via Win API

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to monitor changes of particular set of files (or just one file) and let Windows report to my application.
It's likely, that most of the files will be in same directory, but I'd prefer per-file monitoring system.

I found this example http://codewee.com/view.php?idx=20
but the example monitors only special, Desktop folder.

First by calling *SHGetSpecialFolderLocation*, then using resultant LPITEMIDLIST
in **SHChangeNotifyRegister** function (via *SHChangeNotifyEntry* struct)

I was not able to generalize it to arbitrary directory.
MS Docs says that *SHGetSpecialFolderLocation* will not be supported in future anyway,
*SHGetFolderLocation* should be used instead.

But again, *SHGetFolderLocation* is deprecated, not even mentioning it has no string/path 
parameter.

Is there any convenient function which takes directory path or complete file name
and produces LPITEMIDLIST, which can be then sticked into *SHChangeNotifyRegister*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FindFirstChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) et al.

[`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw), [`ReadDirectoryChangesExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesexw)

[`SHParseDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shparsedisplayname) can be used to convert a file path to `PIDL`, for use with `SHChangeNotifyRegister`